# Composer Yii2 - install kartik

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2

When I type:

php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-money "*"

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 == 2.0.1.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have Yii 2.0.1 installed on my server and here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",

    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Did you check for the potential causes? Did you read the troubleshooting website? What was the outcome? Please gather this information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27703230/edit) your post.

Comment: Could you show your composer.json? There is some components versions mismatch.

Comment: I actually installed 2.0.1. yii on server and on local its 2.0.0. Also, I uploaded composer.phar, composer.json from local and here we are.

Here is how composer.json looks like:

"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-money) and its required [base](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base) have stable releases so I think this setting:

```
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

shouldn't cause the error.

Most likely you simply forgot to install composer asset plugin (read more in official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) and extension [page](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin)).
To install it just execute this command once:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"
```